# should I port my entire site to Drupal to use ubercart for selling my inventory?

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

I would like to use Drupal + ubercart to sell my products on my site. I already have a working, live site (written using only HTML and CSS) and would just like to add the ability to sell/manage inventory to the site without messing with it too much. Is it possible to simply add the ubercart functionality to just the inventory portion of the site, or is it necessary or easier to maintain in the longterm to port my entire site to Drupal first?

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on your existing site. My guess is that it isn't to big, which means migrating the content will not be too much work. I would integrate everything into one system. This makes it much easier to have a consistent look and feel.

If you're starting new, I'd recommend drupal 7 and commerce instead of ubercart. [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) is a good starting point.